# VS 2019 Visual Basic navigation bar class list not refreshing when selecting

Tags: vb.net

I recently installed VS 2019 Preview, and i'm facing this issue:
In my VB code editor, in the navigation bar, when i try to choose a class (button, dropdowlist,...) it's not working: the list of classes it's not refreshing, the class i tried to select is not selected, so i can't be able to edit/create an event for the class i need to edit. I manually have to search for the event, or to create it manually.

Is it malfunction of the Editor? is it a bad configuration? or do i need to re-install VS 2019 ...?
Thanks in advance, looking forward for your comments on above.

Comment: Also make sure to start with **Open a project or solution** and **not** *Open a local folder*. Opening a local folder is only useful when not working with .NET languages and files. The magic only happens when opening a project or solution. See also [Solution Explorer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/solutions-and-projects-in-visual-studio?view=vs-2019).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  thanks for your kind answer. I just ensured to start with "Open a project or solution", but it's still not working.

Comment: Which Framework version are you using? Winforms might not be fully functional yet in .Net 5.0 (.NET Core).

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes  i am using .NET 4.6  ... one more thing: my coworkers don't have this issue.  Dunno if it's an corrupt installation or something

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure why your chose the Preview edition. I never used it. I have the latest VS 2019. In my version I can choose any control on the form in the middle drop down and the events for that control appear in the right drop down.

Another way to add the stub for an event procedure. Is available in Design View. Select a control and view the properties window. On the toolbar choose the lightning bolt. All the events for that control are listed. Double click on the event you want and the stub will be inserted in the code editor.

Of course, you can always just type in the event procedure, as long as it has the correct signature and handles clause, it will work.

Comment: i didn't  choose this version ... my technical leader gave the order  hahahahaha ... i was happy with VS 2017. I will give it a try to the workaround you propose. Thanks for your kind comment.